# Arules (R) apriori on sales data columns are not logical or a factor, use as.factor etc

Tags: r, methods, apriori, arules

Here is what I ran. I recently got answered on preparation of the data so that's fine. I ran the trans command and then got unique values. My data IS in a basket form and is ready. I ran `Arules` on my `AllSales` table now as follows:

```
rules = apriori(AllSales, parameter = list(support(0.001),confidence = 0.5))
```

> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>     column(s) 1, 2 not logical or a factor. Use as.factor, as.logical or categorize 
> first.

Question is, how do I set my columns up now as a factor, logical, or categorized? I'm looking for direct instructions on this as I've looked around plenty and found no set instructions on this.

My first column is the Order# and my second is the Part#, but already set up in basket form.

Thank you.

Comment: To make a dataframe object that is all factor: `AllSales[] <- lapply(AllSales, factor)`. You should probably look at the object first and remove any numeric values that would mess up the logic of apriori.

Comment: Alright, doing that works. It sets it as a factor. when I run "rules = apriori...." command it works and creates a rules table. My Order#'s are numbers as well as the Part#'s. Will this mess up the data? It worked. When I try it with the PartDescription (creating the transaction with trans/split), it gives errors yet it's all unique, so I am forced to use the Part#'s

Comment: With no description of the data, it seems highly optimistic of you to think we can give useful advice. Post a small dataset similar to your problem and code that loads the package and calls the function.